# passing class public properties into view files and access them using $this

Tags: php, laravel

is there a way to access all public properties for both Controller and ChildController 
from view file using **$this**

```
<?PHP 

class Controller {

     public $userFamilyName = "Doe";

}

class ChildController extends Controller{

     public $user = "John"

     public function routeFunction(){
         return view("viewFile")
     }

}
```

**View File => viewFile.blade.php**

```
<header>Hello {$this->user} {$this->userFamilyName} !</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `View::share` to make properties avaiable in your view file with $this

```php
class ChildController extends Controller{

     public $user = "John"

     public function __construct()
     {
         \View::share('user', $this->user);
         \View::share('userFamilyName', $this->userFamilyName);
     }

     public function routeFunction(){
         return view("viewFile")
     }

}
```

Can now be accessed in blade with `{{ $this->user }}`.

Read more about sharing data in views:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#sharing-data-with-all-views